# Problema con las clases duplicadas en Android Studio con Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Soy novato en esto y necesito que alguien me ayude con el siguiente error:

Estoy desarrollando una app con Realidad Aumentada con Android Studio en Lenguaje Kotlin. Al momento de ejecutar la aplicación me aparecen estos errores y la verdad no entiendo que toca hacer.

> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)
> Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules core-1.10.1-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.10.1) and support-compat-27.1.0-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0)

Este es el código Kotlin

```
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.ar.core.Anchor
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult
import com.google.ar.core.Plane
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode
import com.joanhac.realidadaumentada.R
    
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var arFragment: ArFragment
    private lateinit var model1Button: ImageButton
    private lateinit var model2Button: ImageButton
    private lateinit var model3Button: ImageButton
    private lateinit var model4Button: ImageButton
    private lateinit var model5Button: ImageButton
    private var model: ModelRenderable? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        arFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.sceneView) as ArFragment
        model1Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonModel1)
        model2Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonModel2)
        model3Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonModel3)
        model4Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonModel4)
        model5Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonModel5)

        model1Button.setOnClickListener { loadModel(R.raw.horse) }
        model2Button.setOnClickListener { loadModel(R.raw.horse) }
        model3Button.setOnClickListener { loadModel(R.raw.horse) }
        model4Button.setOnClickListener { loadModel(R.raw.horse) }
        model5Button.setOnClickListener { loadModel(R.raw.horse) }

        arFragment.setOnTapArPlaneListener { hitResult: HitResult, plane: Plane, motionEvent ->
            val anchor = hitResult.createAnchor()
            placeModel(anchor)
        }
    }

    private fun loadModel(modelResource: Int) {

        ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(this, modelResource)
            .build()
            .thenAccept { modelRenderable -> model = modelRenderable }
            .exceptionally {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al cargar el modelo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                null
            }
    }

    private fun placeModel(anchor: Anchor) {
        model?.let { modelRenderable ->
            val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
            val transformableNode = TransformableNode(arFragment.transformationSystem)
            transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
            transformableNode.renderable = modelRenderable
            arFragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
            transformableNode.select()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: El código y el error deben ir como texto, por favor ;)

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Comment: Listo @Israel-ICM